# criar view php/oracle

Tags: php, oracle, select, sql-view

Pretendo gerar uma view através do php para um banco oracle onde o select é feito através do resultado de outra consulta.

Esta consulta, monta os select para a view:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT TESTE FROM VIEW_TESTE";
$result1 = odbc_exec($conOraSql , $sql1);
while ($row1 = odbc_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $arrData[] = $row1["TESTE"]."<br />";   
}
$select = implode('',$arrData);
```

O resultado desta consulta:

```
SELECT 'VAL1' COL1, 'VAL2' COL2, 'VAL3' COL3, 'VAL4' COL4, 'VAL5' COL5, 'VAL6' COL6, 'VAL7' COL7, 'VAL8' COL8 FROM VIEW TABELA1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'VAL1' COL1, 'VAL2' COL2, 'VAL3' COL3, 'VAL4' COL4, 'VAL5' COL5, 'VAL6' COL6, 'VAL7' COL7, 'VAL8' COL8 FROM VIEW TABELA2 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'VAL1' COL1, 'VAL2' COL2, 'VAL3' COL3, 'VAL4' COL4, 'VAL5' COL5, 'VAL6' COL6, 'VAL7' COL7, 'VAL8' COL8 FROM VIEW TABELA3
```

E com este resultado, queria montar uma view desta forma, mas sem sucesso, alguma dica?

```
$sql2 = "CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW \"USUARIO\".\"VIEW_TESTE2\" (\"COL1\", \"COL2\", \"COL3\", \"COL4\", \"COL5\", \"COL6\", \"COL7\", \"COL8\") AS $select";
$result2 = odbc_exec($conOraSql , $sql2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para a questão acima, deixo aqui a solução que encontrei:

```
<?php
    #--> conexao oracle
    require_once("Connections/Conn_Oracle.php");
    #--> monta a consulta
    $sql = "CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW \"USUARIO\".\"VIEW1\" (\"TESTE\") AS 
    SELECT 'SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8 FROM ' || a.OWNER || ' WHERE COL1 = 'ALGO' AND COL5 IN (''ALGO2'', ''ALGO3'', ''ALGO4'') UNION ALL '  TESTE FROM ALL_TABLES a ORDER BY a.OWNER";
    $result = odbc_exec($conOraSql , $sql);
    #--> verifica o resultado
    if(!$result) { echo odbc_error()."<br />"; } else { echo 'VIEW1 CRIADA'."<br />"; }
    #-->
    #--> consulta a view 1
    $sql1 = "SELECT TESTE FROM VIEW1";
    $result1 = odbc_exec($conOraSql , $sql1);
    while ($row1 = odbc_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $arrData[] = $row1["TESTE"];    
    }
    $select = implode('',$arrData);
    #-->
    #--> monta a view2
    $sql2 = ""CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW \"USUARIO\".\"VIEW2\" (\"COL1\", \"COL2\", \"COL3\", \"COL4\", \"COL5\", \"COL6\", \"COL7\", \"COL8\") AS $select";
    $result2 = odbc_exec($conOraSql , $sql2);;
    #--> verifica o resultado
    if(!$result2) { echo odbc_error()."<br />"; } else { echo 'VIEW2 CRIADA'."<br />"; }
?>
```